# How to render a page to base url in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I need to render a page for base url in react. I defined base url as,

```
<Router basename="/baseUrl">
 <Switch>
   <Route path={"/childUrl"}
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

I am able to render page via /baseUrl/childUrl. When accessing, /baseUrl it redirects to /baseUrl/childUrl. How can I set a different page to /baseUrl

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but in case anyone else stumbles upon this I would recommend using redux-first-router. It lets you dispatch actions either by changing the url in your browser, or the regular react way. This lets you control how components are rendered and keep the state of your application in sync with the url, without having multiple sources of truth.

Michael Sargent did a brilliant explanation, which can be found [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/an-introduction-to-the-redux-first-routing-model-98926ebf53cb).
And of course, you can also check out the [git repo](https://github.com/faceyspacey/redux-first-router).